# how to set a default value for "Status" field on Item Fulfillment Form in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I just enable PICK, PACK AND SHIP in netsuite. However, i still like to have the Status field to have the default value of Shipped when create a Item Fulfillment. However, i am not able to see find the "Status" on the Custom Transaction Form. Anyone one have a idea?

I tried to re login. still not able to find it